# How to define a colorband in Blender 2.74 using python script

Tags: python, materials

I need to define a colorband using python script, but I don't know how to do this in Blender 2.74. In 2.49 version has a command `colorbandDiffuse` but in 2.74 version I can't find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cycles and Blender Internal render engines have a different Materials ecosystem. They're similar in many ways, but different on important details.

**Blender Internal**

```
import bpy

mat = bpy.data.materials.new('experiment')
mat.use_diffuse_ramp = True
elem = mat.diffuse_ramp.elements.new(0.25)
elem.color = (1,0.2,0.3,0.3)
```

**Cycles**

Involves adding nodes, or appending a premade material from a different .blend (also easy but a different topic)

```
import bpy

mat = bpy.data.materials.new('experiment4')
mat.use_nodes = True

ramp_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeValToRGB')
elements = ramp_node.color_ramp.elements

elem = elements.new(0.25)
elem.color = (1,0.2,0.3,0.3)

# the default 'new material' always has a 'Diffuse BSDF' node, 
# here we obtain a reference to it
diffuse_node = mat.node_tree.nodes['Diffuse BSDF']

# nodes need to be hooked up!
mat.node_tree.links.new(ramp_node.outputs[0], diffuse_node.inputs[0])
```

The reason I mention appending an existing material is because it can be a lot more convenient to tailor a complex material once and use many variations of it in subsequent blends by appending the material and adjusting known values. Scripting Cycles materials can be a little verbose :)

If you still have questions then hopefully you'll have some idea what to ask about.